# Cisco Enhanced Object Tracking

Tags: cisco, routing

I'm trying to configure our router so that if BGP goes down our interface, FastEthernet0/0/0.3861 59.X.X.X would change from administrative down (SHUT) to UP.

I think this can be achieved with Cisco Enhanced Object Tracking. Alternatively, if I could configure the Tunnel interface (1) to be in standby mode while BGP is up and when bgp fails, to change from standby to up.

Sorry if this is confusing, but anyone with Cisco skills will probably understand.

The configuration is as follows:

```
our_production_router2#show run 

Building configuration...

Current configuration : 17642 bytes 
! 
! 
Last configuration change at 14:54:15 UTC Wed Apr 13 2016 by johnsonmatthey\pattec0 
! 
version 15.4 
service timestamps debug datetime msec 
service timestamps log datetime msec 
service password-encryption 
! 
hostname jmeu-gurgaon02 
! 
boot-start-marker 
boot-end-marker 
! 
! 
logging buffered 51200 warnings 
enable password 7 ****************** 
! 
aaa new-model 
! 
! 
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.10.1 
! 
ip dhcp pool ccp-pool 
 import all 
 network 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.128 
 default-router 10.10.10.1 
  lease 0 2
!
! 
! 
no ip bootp server 
no ip domain lookup 
ip domain name routers.matthey.com 
ip name-server 192.168.1.233 
ip name-server 192.168.1.253 
ip cef 
no ipv6 cef 
! 
multilink bundle-name authenticated 
! 
cts logging verbose 
! 
! 
! 
interface Loopback0 
 ip address 10.41.252.72 255.255.255.255 
 no ip redirects 
 no ip unreachables 
 no ip proxy-arp 
 ip flow ingress 
! 
interface Loopback1 
 description BT Peering Loopback 
 ip address 10.1.243.106 255.255.255.255 
! 
interface Tunnel1 
 description Tunnel to jmeu-london-colo01 
 bandwidth 20000 
 ip address 10.9.249.34 255.255.255.252 
 no ip redirects 
 no ip unreachables 
 no ip proxy-arp 
 ip mtu 1420 
 ip hello-interval eigrp 65100 10 
 ip hold-time eigrp 65100 180 
 ip flow ingress 
 ip flow egress 
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1140 
 keepalive 4 6 
 tunnel source x.x.x.x 
 tunnel destination x.x.x.x 
 tunnel path-mtu-discovery 
 crypto map JMEU-VPN 
! 
interface Tunnel3 
 description Tunnel to jmeu-taloja01 
 bandwidth 256 
 ip address 10.41.248.18 255.255.255.252 
 no ip redirects 
 no ip unreachables 
 no ip proxy-arp 
 ip flow ingress 
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1340 
 keepalive 4 6 
 tunnel source x.x.x. 
 tunnel destination x.x.x.x 
 crypto map JMEU-VPN 
! 
interface Tunnel4 
 description p2p tunnel to Manesar 
 bandwidth 256 
 backup interface Tunnel3 
 ip address 10.41.249.170 255.255.255.252 
 no ip redirects 
 no ip unreachables 
 no ip proxy-arp 
 ip flow ingress 
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1340 
 keepalive 4 6 
 tunnel source x.x.x. 
 tunnel destination x.x.x.x 
 crypto map JMEU-VPN 
! 
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0 
 no ip address 
 shutdown 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet0/0 
 description $ETH-LAN$$ETH-SW-LAUNCH$$INTF-INFO-GE 0/0$ 
 ip address 192.168.230.129 255.255.255.192 
 ip mtu 1420 
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1140 
 duplex auto 
 speed auto 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet0/1 
 bandwidth 10000 
 no ip address 
 no ip redirects 
 no ip unreachables 
 no ip proxy-arp 
 ip mtu 1420 
 ip flow ingress 
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1140 
 duplex auto 
 speed 10 
 no cdp enable 
 no mop enabled 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.2997 
 description CID:  
 bandwidth 10000 
 encapsulation dot1Q 2997 
 ip address 10.1.243.166 255.255.255.252 
 no cdp enable 
! 
interface FastEthernet0/0/0 
 no ip address 
 ip access-group Permitted-Inbound-Internet in 
 duplex auto 
 speed auto 
! 
interface FastEthernet0/0/0.3861 
 encapsulation dot1Q 3861 
 ip address x.x.x.x 255.255.255.252 
 ip access-group Permitted-Inbound-Internet in 
 no ip redirects 
 no ip unreachables 
 no ip proxy-arp 
 ip mtu 1420 
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1400 
 no cdp enable 
 crypto map JMEU-VPN 
! 
interface FastEthernet0/0/1 
 no ip address 
 duplex auto 
 speed auto 
! 
! 
router eigrp 65100 
 network 10.0.0.0 
 network 192.168.230.0 
 redistribute static metric 1500 1000 255 1 1500 route-map allow-static-routes 
 redistribute bgp 65304 metric 1500 1000 255 1 1500 
! 
router bgp 65304 
 bgp log-neighbor-changes 
 neighbor 10.1.243.165 remote-as 12641 
 ! 
 address-family ipv4 
  network 10.41.252.2 mask 255.255.255.255 
  network 10.41.252.72 mask 255.255.255.255 
  network 192.168.230.128 mask 255.255.255.192 
  neighbor 10.1.243.165 activate 
  neighbor 10.1.243.165 soft-reconfiguration inbound 
 exit-address-family 
! 
ip forward-protocol nd 
! 
ip http server 
ip http access-class 23 
ip http authentication local 
no ip http secure-server 
ip http timeout-policy idle 600 life 86400 requests 10000 
ip flow-export source Loopback0 
ip flow-export version 5 
! 
ip tacacs source-interface Loopback0 
! 
logging trap notifications 
logging source-interface Loopback0 
logging host 192.168.1.222 
logging host 10.16.1.252 
logging host 192.168.151.154 
! 
route-map allow-static-routes permit 10 
 match ip address 10 
! 
route-map static-to-bgp permit 10 
 match tag 111 
! 
! 
key 7 095B411B1501071D07051023282524 
access-list 1 permit 192.168.230.0 0.0.0.255 
access-list 10 remark redistribute-statics-first-line-dummy 
access-list 10 permit 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.255 
access-list 23 permit 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.127 
access-list 23 permit 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.7 
! 
! 
! 
control-plane 
! 
!

!
!
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the state of an interface based on an event, you should look at the Cisco Embedded Event Manager scripting: [EEM Configuration for Cisco Integrated Services Router Platforms](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/ios-nx-os-software/ios-embedded-event-manager-eem/config_guide_eem_configuration_for_cisco_integrated_services_router_platforms.html)

Based on an event, the script can perform something like this:

```
ROUTER(config-applet)# action 1.2 cli command "interface g0/1"
ROUTER(config-applet)# action 1.3 cli command "no shut"
```

> **Example 1: Command Execution with Logged Event**
>
> This example illustrates the use of EEM to execute show commands when
>   a particular
>   event occurs and collect the output and save it in some location that
>   you can use for troubleshooting later. Figure 2 shows the topology.
>
> Challenge
>
> This example shows how to collect CPU usage and interface
>   output when the Open Shortest Path First (OSPF) neighbor is down in
>   router B.
>
> Solution
>
> EEM is configured to check for an OSPF-neighbor-down syslog
>   message; if it occurs, it executes the following command and saves the
>   output in flash memory:
>
> - show cpu process
> - show interfaces
>
> The configuration follows:
>
> ```
> RouterB#sh run
> Building configuration...
> Current configuration : 1137 bytes
> !
> version 12.4
> service timestamps debug datetime msec
> service timestamps log datetime msec
> no service password-encryption
> !
> hostname RouterB
> ip cef
> !
> interface Loopback0
> ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
> !
> interface GigabitEthernet0/0
> ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
> duplex auto
> speed auto
> !
> interface GigabitEthernet0/1
> no ip address
> shutdown
> duplex auto
> speed auto
> !
> router ospf 1
> log-adjacency-changes
> network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
> line con 0
> exec-timeout 0 0
> line aux 0
> line vty 0 4
> login
> !
> scheduler allocate 20000 1000
> !
> webvpn cef
> !
> event manager applet OSPF
> event syslog pattern "Neighbor Down: Dead timer expired"
> action 1.0 cli command "enable"
> action 1.1 cli command "sh proc cpu | append flash:cpu_info"
> action 1.2 cli command "show interface | append flash:interface_info"
> action 1.6 syslog msg "OSPF NEIGHBOR DOWN"
> !
> end
> RouterB#
> ```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Can I add more than one event to an applet? e.g could I add "Neighbor Up:" event to the same applet OSPF ?

Comment: You would want a different one for that. You can have multiple applets, and each looks for different events and performs actions based on the events.